# jQuery error with pipe symbol "|" in ID name

Tags: javascript, jquery, element, pipe

I have a select menu, it's options are ID'd like this:

```
<select>
<option id='order1|2'>1</option>
<option id='order2|2'>2</option>
<option id='order3|2'>3</option>
</select>
```

I want to select one dynamically with jQuery. In javascript, I can do

```
document.getElementById("order2|2").selected=true;
```

and that works fine. however, with jQuery

```
$("#order2|2").attr("selected","selected");
```

gives a bad expression error, so does any other command when I am working with it, such as

```
$("#order2|2").val();
```

I'm not sure what is happening. jQuery does not like the pipe symbol? Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Use this selector:

```
$("#order2\\|2")
```

From jQuery selectors docs:

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \\.

Reference:

- http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape `|` with `\\`

```
$("#order2\\|2").prop("selected",true);
```

Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/VzAQN/1/

Answer (score 0):

it is all in the documentation:

http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.